# BIRT report created via eclipse throwing error on execution

Tags: java, api, reportviewer, execution

I've a particular birt project which I've created using the eclipse ide. I am trying to understand how to deploy the report without having to use alternatives which would cost something.

So ultimately I am left with the birt report engine api. I've downloaded the report engine runtime package from the birt-exchange web site. I've found a particular script (ms-dos batch file - **genReport.bat**) which can generate reports from the rptdesign file.

There are particular some basic sample reports in this package which demonstrate how we can generate a report. The script is able to execute against these sample reports. However when I try to execute the script against a reports I've created via the birt-eclipse ide I get the following error. (I've pasted it right out of the command prompt):

```
Oct 13, 2009 2:14:46 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ReportEngineHelp
er openReportDesign
SEVERE: invalid design file file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/arun.jayapal/wor
kspace/atsusersReport/atsUsers.rptdesign
Oct 13, 2009 2:14:46 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.ReportRunner runAndRe
nderReport
SEVERE: The design file file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/arun.jayapal/workspa
ce/atsusersReport/atsUsers.rptdesign has error and can not be run.
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: The design file file:/C:/Doc
uments%20and%20Settings/arun.jayapal/workspace/atsusersReport/atsUsers.rptdesign
has error and can not be run.
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ReportEngineHelper.openReport
Design(ReportEngineHelper.java:258)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ReportEngineHelper.openReport
Design(ReportEngineHelper.java:193)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ReportEngineHelper.openReport
Design(ReportEngineHelper.java:127)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ReportEngine.openReportDesign
(ReportEngine.java:349)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.ReportRunner.runAndRenderReport(Re
portRunner.java:192)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.ReportRunner.execute(ReportRunner.
java:165)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.ReportRunner.main(ReportRunner.jav
a:120)
Caused by: Error.DesignFileException.INVALID_XML - 1 errors found!
1.) ( line = 0, tag = null) org.eclipse.birt.report.model.parser.DesignParserE
xception (code = Error.DesignParserException.UNSUPPORTED_VERSION, message : The
report file of version "3.2.20" is invalid for it is greater than the latest sup
ported one.)

at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.parser.ModuleReader.readModule(ModuleRe
ader.java:116)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.parser.DesignReader.read(DesignReader.j
ava:88)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.core.DesignSession.openDesign(DesignSes
sion.java:321)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.api.SessionHandle.openDesign(SessionHan
dle.java:294)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.parser.ReportParser.getDesignHandle(Re
portParser.java:158)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ReportEngineHelper.openReport
Design(ReportEngineHelper.java:253)
... 6 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.report.model.parser.DesignParserException: The repor
t file of version "3.2.20" is invalid for it is greater than the latest supporte
d one.
at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.parser.ModuleState.parseAttrs(ModuleSta
te.java:112)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.parser.ModuleParserHandler.startElement
(ModuleParserHandler.java:229)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startEle
ment(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElem
ent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
l.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$Conten
tDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
l$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$Prolog
Driver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(U
nknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
l.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(U
nknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(U
nknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown So
urce)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Un
known Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.p
arse(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.parser.ModuleReader.readModule(ModuleRe
ader.java:94)
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I've recently done a BIRT deployment and find that it can be kind of finicky. I had the error you're describing when I tried to load and preview reports in eclipse that were generated by someone running a later version of the BIRT eclipse tools.

It looks like the samples you have are out of sync with the environment you're trying to run it on. Try upgrading the environment (since you're in eclipse, that would be your installed birt reporting plugins).

Comment: there are a lot of birt-related jar files in my eclipse's plugin folder. How do I know which are the ones to include? Plus, I did a search in the directory and I couldn't find a batch file (similar to genreport.bat). I know this file is particularly of no pratical use, but still I need to demonstrate ppl that there is a possibility of generating a report...